# how to prevent emacs-org mode code-block's evaluate result tabled

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I use org-mode as following:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh                                                                                                                                               
ulimit -a                                                                                                                                                    
#+END_SRC
```

when i run **C-c C-c** ，the code was evaluated, and the **RESULT** part was formatted as table of org-mode:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh                                                                                                                                               
ulimit -a                                                                                                                                                    
#+END_SRC                                                                                                                                                    

#+RESULTS:
| core       | file     | size      | (blocks,  | -c)       |         0 |
| data       | seg      | size      | (kbytes,  | -d)       | unlimited |
| scheduling | priority | (-e)      | 0         |           |           |
| file       | size     | (blocks,  | -f)       | unlimited |           |
| pending    | signals  | (-i)      | 16448     |           |           |
| max        | locked   | memory    | (kbytes,  | -l)       |        32 |
| max        | memory   | size      | (kbytes,  | -m)       | unlimited |
| open       | files    | (-n)      | 65534     |           |           |
| pipe       | size     | (512      | bytes,    | -p)       |         8 |
| POSIX      | message  | queues    | (bytes,   | -q)       |    819200 |
| real-time  | priority | (-r)      | 0         |           |           |
| stack      | size     | (kbytes,  | -s)       | 10240     |           |
| cpu        | time     | (seconds, | -t)       | unlimited |           |
| max        | user     | processes | (-u)      | 16448     |           |
| virtual    | memory   | (kbytes,  | -v)       | unlimited |           |
| file       | locks    | (-x)      | unlimited |           |           |
```

this was not what I wanted, i hope the result can keep origin format.
so how to prevent the org auto format the result ?

very thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding `:results output raw` should do it.